# D3.js produces valid SVG but shows nothing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my D3.js script:

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100);

svg.append(function () {
    var g = d3.select(document.createElement('g'))
        .attr('width', 50)
        .attr('height', 50);

    g.append('circle').attr('r', 8).attr('cx', 10).attr('cy', 10);
    g.append('text').text("test").attr('x', 25).attr('y', 25);

    return g.node();
});
```

You can check it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gotgo29L/). The script produces [valid SVG code](http://jsfiddle.net/qntqkpfy/):

```
<svg width="100" height="100"><g width="50" height="50"><circle r="8" cx="10" cy="10"></circle><text x="25" y="25">test</text></g></svg>
```

You can use DOM inspector to verify that this really is the code that is generated using the JavaScript above. The problem is that **you can't see anything**. The image simply won't appear. But if you copy the generated SVG code manually into another JSFiddle instance, you can clearly see that the image is there and it works.

I suppose that the problem is in the `append` function and in the fact that I'm passing a function as the argument instead of an element name. This is, however, a supported feature according to the documentation. And it's really weird because apparently the DOM is changed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) instead of `createElement`, and supply the correct namespace – otherwise you are only creating elements that happen to have the *“right” name*, but are not *recognized as* SVG elements by the browser.

```
var g = d3.select(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gotgo29L/1/